# Can someone explain me what is flex property?

Tags: css, flexbox

Hello currently I'm learning flexbox, and I've watched a lot tutorials but I couldn't figure out what does flex property do? Some explanation and links that explain what it does would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Have any of the answers so far answered your question? If so, please accept the best one so that other users who have the same question can find the information more easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As T. Evans mentioned, the `flex` property is shorthand for three other properties: `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`. You can set the values of each property by giving the `flex` property three values, in this order:

```
flex: [flex-grow] [flex-shrink] [flex-basis]
```

For example, `flex: 0 1 auto;`

Now, let’s briefly review what each of those three properties means.

**Flex-grow**

We use this property on a child element of a flex-box. It sets how large the element will be in proportion to the other elements. The default value of `flex-grow` is 0, so setting `flex-grow` to larger than 0 will make the element larger than other elements. (You can’t set it to a negative number, though.)

*Example 1:* Here, we use `flex-grow` to make one element twice as large as the other. A `flex-grow` of 2 on one element and 1 on the other element means that the elements will have a 2-to-1 size ratio.  Setting one `flex-grow` to 8 and the other to 4 would do the exact same thing, since 2:1 is the same ratio as 8:4.

```css
#flexbox {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#big {
  flex-grow: 2;
  background-color: lavender;
}

#small {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox">
  <div id="big">BIG</div>
  <div id="small">SMALL</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/50rhpdxe/7/)

*Example 2:* Here, we set `flex-grow` on only one element while leaving the other at its default of 0. This makes the element grow to fill as much space as possible. We can use any value for `flex-grow` and it will work exactly the same, as long as the other element has `flex-grow: 0;`

```css
#flexbox {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#big {
  flex-grow: 5;
  background-color: lavender;
}

#small {
  /* flex-grow is 0 by default */
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox">
  <div id="big">BIG</div>
  <div id="small">SMALL</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/domg1wts/)

**Flex-shrink**

This property works similarly to `flex-grow`, but the ratio describes how much smaller one element should be than another. Also, the default value is one.

*Example:* If we set one element’s `flex-shrink` to 2 and the others' to 1, when the parent element is too small to fit every element comfortably and the children must shrink, that element will shrink more than the other elements.

```css
#flexbox {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#flexbox div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  background-color: lavender;
}

#flexbox #small {
  flex-shrink: 4;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox">
  <div>NORMAL</div>
  <div id="small">SMALL</div>
  <div>NORMAL</div>
  <div>NORMAL</div>
  <div>NORMAL</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hxk8rj9/)

**Flex-basis**

This property sets the initial size of the element. Its value can be either `auto`, which sets the initial size automatically, or a number of pixels or other size units (like % or vw, for example.) The default value is `auto`.

*Example:* Here, we set most of the elements to have an initial size of 50px and set their `flex-grow` to 1 so that they will grow to fill the space. However, one element has a `flex-basis` of 100px, so it will be larger than the other elements. Try resizing the window to see how this example behaves.

```css
#flexbox {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#flexbox div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50px;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  background-color: lavender;
}

#flexbox #large {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox">
  <div>NORMAL</div>
  <div id="large">LARGE</div>
  <div>NORMAL</div>
  <div>NORMAL</div>
  <div>NORMAL</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4L17a6fj/)

**Putting it all together**

As we mentioned before, the `flex` property combines all three of those properties into one. If we wanted to set the `flex-grow` of an element to 1, the `flex-shrink` to 2, and the `flex-basis` to 100px, we could use `flex` and shorten this:

```
#child {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 2;
    flex-basis: 100px;
}
```

To this:

```
#child {
    flex: 1 2 100px;
}
```

Comment: This is an amazing solution!!

Answer (score 0):

Flex Property is referring to a shorthand.

Basically it looks like this : `flex: <flex-grow> <flex-shrink> <flex-basis>`

This refers to how the items work more in a `display: flex`...

For more on this I would suggest looking at the following links:

[W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)

[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/)

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)